# Laravel: Sorting a collection with a many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, collections

I have two tables: `assessments` and `benchmarks`. `benchmarks` has a field called `content`. There is a many to many relationship between them: `assessment_benchmark`. I want to sort a collection of records from the `assessment_benchmark` table by the `content` attribute of the corresponding benchmark. I have tried:

```
$sorted = AssessmentBenchmark::all()->sortBy(function($assessmentBenchmark){
    return $assessmentBenchmark->benchmark->content;
});
```

But this just does not work (it just returns the original order). However, when I return `$assessmentBenchmark->comment` for example, it does work (comment is a field in `assessment_benchmark`).

The models look like this:

```
class AssessmentBenchmark extends Model
{
  public function benchmark()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Benchmark::class);
  }

  public function assessment()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Assessment::class);
  }
}



class Benchmark extends Model
{
  public function assessments()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Assessment::class);
  }
}



class Assessment extends Model
{
   public function benchmarks()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Benchmark::class);
   }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with `$benchmarks = Benchmark::orderBy('content', 'desc')->get();` ? After fetching you can fetch its assessments

Comment: I can do that, but I don't want the benchmarks in order, nor the assessments. I want the AssessmentBenchmarks to be in order (based on the content of the benchmark)

Comment: in fact you don't need `AssessmentBenchmark` model because you can do all the operations for `Benchmark` and `Assessment` without Pivot Model, until you have some specific requirement. If it is then you can specify it in your question

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify what I'm trying to do. I'm using DataTables to show (and make it possible to edit) all the AssessmentBenchmarks of a certain assessment. I'm saying AssessmentBenchmarks, not benchmarks, since a AssessmentBenchmark consists of certain information which is not in a benchmark. So basically, I have information in the intermediate table that belong to a certain combination of an assessment and a benchmark.

Comment: I want to save certain information to a AssessmentBenchmark, so I need to work with those

Comment: if you have some information in intermediate table then you can specify it in `belongsToMany` relationship as `pivot` field and then you can fetch that pivot field and update it too. If you add your  `assessment_benchmark` table structure in your code then we can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178432/discussion-between-jordi-verheul-and-rkj).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use below query for sorting, I'm gonna use Assessment model, because, I'm never use pivot modal before. Actually, I never had pivot model..

```
$assessments = Assessment::with(["benchmarks"=>function($query){
   $query->orderBy("content","DESC");
}])
```

With method aşso provide you eagerloading, so when you put `$assessments` in iteration , you won't make new query for each relation

Answer (score 0):

From chat discussion, it found that you have pivot field and for that you can change your `belongsToMany` relationship like this

```
class Benchmark extends Model
{
  public function assessments()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Assessment::class)->withPivot('comment','score')->withTimestamps();
  }
}


class Assessment extends Model
{
   public function benchmarks()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Benchmark::class)->withPivot('comment','score')->withTimestamps();
   }
}
```

Now fetch data

```
$assessment = Assessment::with(['benchmarks' => function($query){ 
       $query->orderBy('content', 'desc'); 
}])->find($assessmentId);
```

In view you can render it like this

```
@foreach($assessment->benchmarks as $benchmark)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$benchmark->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$benchmark->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$benchmark->pivot->score}}</td>
        <td>{{$benchmark->pivot->comment}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

For update  you can use `updateExistingPivot`

For details check ManyToMany relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many